# Local & LocalLow folders getting copied into roaming profile on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, roaming-profiles

Existing Windows 7/8.1 environment with Windows 2012 domain controller. Domain accounts configured to use roaming profiles. Works fine on existing clients copying just the "Roaming" sub-folder under AppData to the server. Specifically Local and LocalLow don't roam which has always been the case with Windows.

New Windows 10 Pro VM built and when the VM is restarted - causing the user to log off - it's copying all three sub-folders Roaming, Local & LocalLow to the roaming profile. Given that many apps store lots of temporary files & caches in Local & LocalLow, this behaviour really slows down log off. It also significantly increases the size of the roaming profile on the server.

Any ideas? I know that Windows 10 introduces the new v5 profile folder - which is where the three folders are ending up. Any references to anything in Windows 10 re: changes to the roaming profile system? All I can find is stuff about the new v5 profile.

Comment: The VM in question has been loaded up with quite a few applications. I've just restored the VM to a very early snapshot (basically Windows 10 & Office 2013) and this problem does not occur. It therefore suggests it was something installed later in the build so am going into divide and conquer mode to try and track it down

Comment: Hmm, occurs on basic Windows 10 & Office 2013 VM. Not good... problem is that you end up with group policy stuff (in AppData\Local) and loads of "access denied" errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (2015/09/02):** I still see this happening intermittently, though much less frequently after installing the KBs listed below. Per [this Microsoft support thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f333c4d3-bbf2-40a9-a7d3-4267f656124b/windows-10-roaming-profile-includes-appdatalocal-localnow-folders?forum=win10itprogeneral), this is a known issue with unclear cause.

It looks like this was solved by either [KB3081438](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081438) or [KB3081444](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081444).

I saw this happening a number of times on Windows 10, where Local and LocalLow folders were synced to `%USERNAME%.v5`. Nothing seemed to solve this -- including manually excluding those folders by updating `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]`

Now -- and after those two cumulative KBs rolled out -- it looks like Local & LocalLow are no longer copied to roaming profile (and are removed if present).

Comment: Hmm, I've been rebuilding the VM application by application over the past few days and I've just triggered Local & LocalNow - the application that seemed to cause the problem was Corel Paintshop Pro X7. It's late here so I'm going to try repeating a few times tomorrow

Comment: But the second KB3081444 was installed on 24/08 (yesterday) so maybe this is a separate fault. More tests needed...

Comment: Ahh, you're definitely onto something here as those KBs are all about Internet Explorer. I've just rolled back the VM prior to Paintshop and launched IE11. Guess what - Local and LocalLow appear at reboot. NOTE: the 2nd KB is present in this VM so my tests show it's NOT fixed.

Comment: And reason Corel Paintshop Pro X7 is triggering the problem as it opens a web page as part of the installation. I'm guessing if I go back to a very early image and open IE11 then the problem will reoccur

Comment: Do you have any references to a discussion about this fault and those KBs?

Comment: Just an observation -- I haven't found any release notes from Microsoft (which is pretty absurd). I just noticed that as those KBs rolled out, the problem seemed to go away after a reboot or two.


KB3081444 touches all kinds of kernel code, etc. No way it's just an IE11 patch (as their description implies).

Comment: Ahh thanks - not had chance over last couple of days to follow-up

Comment: I have a fully patched Enterprise x64 install including the KBs mentioned above and am still seeing this problem.

Comment: Come back to this problem today and I'm unable to repeat it but the W10 VM has just installed some updates so hopefully this is now resolved

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with Windows 7 as well - I don't think those KBs help me :-(

Comment: The problem is still present (August 2018) with a newly installed and fully updated W10, it seems that installation of some software triggers it.